# What are the standings requirements (if any) to anchor a POS in low sec?

Tags: eve-online

I'm looking to anchor a POS in a low security system in EVE, but I can't seem to find a conclusive answer to the question above.  Some guides seem to indicate that standings aren't required to anchor in low security space while other guides seem to indicate that I can only anchor in systems with a security level of (0.10 * (Faction Standing)).  I'm not really sure which guides are right and which are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Incursion patch notes: "You can now anchor a POS in a 0.4 system without faction standing."
[Incursion Patch Notes, Build 221279](http://community.eveonline.com/updates/patchnotes.asp?newpatchlogID=2884)

So you do not need standing to anchor in low or null.

Comment: Thanks!  I must have spent at least an hour googling, but I never came across those patch notes.

Answer (score 2):

You can anchor freely in null sec (0.0) space, low sec has standing requirements.

Between 0.1 and 0.7, you require a faction standing of 10*sec, specifically from [EveOnline Wiki](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Empire_space)

> Anchoring a POS in Empire space requires faction with the region's controller, calculated by the formula 10 x system security level. Example: You are trying to anchor a POS in an Amarr Empire controlled system with a security level of 0.5. You must take 10 x 0.5 to calculate the standing you will need with the Amarr Empire to anchor a POS, in this case it would be 5.0. This standing is required from your corporation to faction that holds sovereignity and are updated at downtime. It's value is an average of corporation members standings to faction.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, I've seen that wiki entry, but then I've also come across other resources that claim that, as of one of the more recent updates, they removed the standings to anchor.  I was hoping somebody here may have first hand experience and be able to say definitively whether or not standings are needed in low sec.

Comment: Oh I can't say then. Last time I played standings were certainly needed, since you had to "fuel" them with documents.